# How to query Airtable to filter record using IN keyword for a column?

Tags: airtable

I have a table named Product with different categories now I want to filter products based on categories mention by the user
Column name: Category,
array containing `Values:['clothing','shoes','sports']`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the requirement. "Categories mentioned by the user Column name"? Could you elaborate?

If you're looking to apply a filter to a view or three, you can literally just click through your requirements using the UI.

Multiple select fields can be queries in a variety of ways.

You could flatten them with a formula like this:

```
ARRAYFLATTEN(
  {your_field_name}
  ) & ''
```

Then use REGEX_MATCH or any of the other text processing formulas for more robust filtering. Regular expressions seem like a decent option here, as it sounds like you're primarily interested in simple keyword matching. That's precisely what they excel at. [Here's where to start learning Airtable's regex implementation](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500001653982-Guide-to-REGEX-functions).

That " & ''" part in the above formula sets you up with a more searchable target as it coerces the array value into a string that you can then take apart with regex. Wrapping the entire field output into a **T()** call would have done the job here, as well.

Also, both Lookup and Rollup fields allow you to apply selective filtering logic to your array fields.